# EF Core - Many-To-Many Relationship across 4 Tables

Tags: entity-framework, orm, relational-database, ef-core-2.1

Consider the following 3 entities `A`, `B`, and `C`. `A`-to-`C` is a many-to-many relationship. `B`-to-`A` is a one-to-many relationship (`B` has many `A`, which implies `B`-to-`C` is also many-to-many).

If these overcomplicated relationships seems too vague to you, please consider this example:

- a `Track` (`A`) has multiple `Artist`s (`C`), an `Artist` has multiple `Track`s (Many-to-Many)
- an `Album` (`B`) has multiple `Track`s. (One-to-Many, a `Track` *cannot* belong to multiple `Album`s)

so that (implication):

- an `Album` has multiple `Artist`s, and an `Artist` has multiple `Album`s (Many-to-Many)

Question: **How to entities with such relationships?** With the following code, I've established relationships between `Album`-to-`Artist`, `Track`-to-`Artist`. **How to create `Artist`-`Album` relationship** as it seems to require joining 4 tables/entities.

```
public class Context: DbContext
{

    // irrelevant code omitted...        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TracksToArtists>()
            .HasKey(r => new {r.TrackId, r.ArtistId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<TracksToArtists>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Track)
            .WithMany(t => t.Artists)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.TrackId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TracksToArtists>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Artist)
            .WithMany(a => a.Tracks)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ArtistId);
    }
}

public class Track
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid AlbumId { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }

    public List<TracksToArtists> Artists { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Track> Tracks { get; set; }

    // TODO: create album-to-artist many-to-many relationship
    // public List<SomethingArtistMaybe?> Artists { get; set; }
}
public class Artist
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<TracksToArtists> Tracks { get; set; }

    // TODO: create album-to-artist many-to-many relationship
    // public List<SomethingAlbumMaybe?> Albums { get; set; }
}
 // many-to-many relationship
public class TracksToArtists
{
    public Guid TrackId { get; set; }
    public Track Track { get; set; }

    public Guid ArtistId { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

It's quite straightforward if just using raw SQL queries, yet with ORM everything becomes a bit painful.

*Optimally*, I'd like to avoid introducing `AlbumToArtist` table as it may create inconsistency in data. It should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: You won't create Album - Artist relationship because it's derived from the other relationships. For instance, album artists are `album.Tracks.SelectMany(track => track.Artists.Select(link => link.Artist))`, respectively artist albums are `artist.Tracks.Select(link => link.Track.Album)`. EF (Core) relationships so far represent only the physical database FK relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `Artist` doesn't have a direct relationship to `Album`, the relationship is only via `Track`.

Consider putting the `Album` in the center, so that each `Artist` has multiple `Album` and vice versa (many-to-many), then have `Album` navigate to many `Track`s (one-to-many).

Anyway, whether you choose to keep your model as in your question or as I suggested, accessing the graph from point to another (in your question `Album`s of each `Artist`), use [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Album>> GetAlbums(Artist artist)
{
    return await myDbContext.Artists
                   .Include(artist => artist.Tracks)
                   .ThenInclude(track => track.Album)
                 .Where(a.Id == artist.Id)
                 .Select(artist => 
                   artist.Tracks.Select(track =>
                     track.Album))
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToListAsync();
}
```

You can also enable [lazy-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) so you don't have to explicitly include the navigation properties in your query, but there is a performance cost for that.